# Chart in React is not displaying

Tags: reactjs, charts

I have written a  basic bar chart code in my react application, but I am not getting anything on the chrome or firefox browser. The code is as given below::

App.js File

```
import './App.css';
import BarChart from './components/barChart';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Chart</h1>
       <BarChart />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

barChart.js file has been created in components folder and its coded as given below:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2'


const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
      }
    ]
  };
function barChart() {
    
    return (
        <div>
           <h2>Bar Example (custom size)</h2>
        <Bar
          data={data}
          width={100}
          height={50}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }}
        />
        <h1>Bar Chart</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default barChart
```

i Had installed npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js

Answer (score 0):

you just need to

```js
import { Chart as ChartJS } from 'chart.js/auto'
```

And your code will work for sure

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, you have to capitalise the names of your `Components` in `React`.

So instead of `function barChart()`, try `function BarChart()`. Remember to correct the import in `App.js` too.